# Display list of year based on date range

Tags: mysql

I want to do an SQL query to display list of year based on date range. Not involving any table. For example,

```
startYear = "2010"
endYear = "2023"
```

Result will be:

```
2010
2011
2012
.
.
.
2023
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my  [source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224182/generate-dates-between-date-ranges-in-mysql).

Like you can see, it created start date and end date and skip on the years by using the key word `year`.

```
  WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
    select '2018-01-01' as Date
   union all
   select Date + interval 1 year
   from Date_Ranges
   where Date < '2021-12-31')
select * from Date_Ranges;
```

Here you can see the results:
[image: thanks https://onecompiler.com/]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GeorgRichter Hi, this is only the output value and the code is not rellevant, did you mean to the source of the compiler?

Comment: Use copy and paste  - and check the link above which expains why you shouldn't attach images.

Comment: @Thescion any clue on how to convert to compatible with mysql 5.6 version?

Comment: @Tora What is your error?

Comment: @Thescion since mysql 5.6 version doesnt support the WITH clause...the sql wont run